# no such column: Schedule_footballscore.match_played

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
class FootballScore(models.Model):
        team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='teams_football', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        match_played = models.IntegerField(default='0')
        lose = models.IntegerField(default='0')
        win = models.IntegerField(default='0')
```

Initially i have **team** and **win** field only, Now i am adding new fields **match_played** and **lose** . When i am doing **python manage.py makemigrations** , no change is displayed, i even tried **python manage.py makemigrations (my_app_name)** . i also tried all the previous answers of Stackoverflow related to this topic.

```
migrations.CreateModel(
    name='FootballScore',
    fields=[
        ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
        ('match_played', models.IntegerField(default='0')),
        ('lose', models.IntegerField(default='0')),
        ('win', models.IntegerField(default='0')),
    ],
),
```

I have seen this migration type of thing in one of the folder, is this the migrated list, because here all my fields are mentioned? Any help will be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps needed are:

- Create your model
- Create an initial migration (`0001_initial`)
- Execute the migration

...

- Add new columns to the model
- Create a new migration to add the columns
- Execute the new migration

Based on your example, you might not have the initial migration without the `match_played` column.

Comment: I am getting your point, but when i am opening my model from admin, "no such column: Schedule_footballscore.match_played" is showing :(

Comment: That happens when there is no such column in the physical database (MySQL/Postgres/...), i.e. when the Model does not match the database table. This is solved by creating and running migrations.

Comment: I just commented the new fields and run makmigrations, it was there, because it was asking to remove those fields, i just removed the fields and added back and it is working fine now. Thanks. I don't know , why it was acting weird previously. Thanks a lot! @AKX